# AWS Cloud9 creates .c9 folder automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, backend, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

sorry if this is a silly question.

I'm currently following along on an online course to learn the basics of coding for the web, and the backend language is ruby which is being written with Cloud9. Part of the course says to delete the files in the environment folder, but this is due to the course being made when Cloud9 was independent software and would launch environments with premade files. When I do go along with it and delete the default readme file a folder called .c9 is created, but stays gone if I then delete it.

Is it better to delete .c9 when it is created, keep it and ignore it when it appears, or to keep and ignore the original readme file?

Comment: Please share your answer in the answer section and leave the question for the question only.

Answer (score -1):

> If the environment was an SSH environment, AWS Cloud9 leaves behind a hidden subdirectory on the cloud compute instance or your own server that was connected to that environment. You can now safely delete that subdirectory if you want to delete it. The subdirectory is named .c9. It's located in the Environment path directory that you specified when you created the environment.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/aws-cloud9-ug.pdf

Answer (score -1):

If the environment was an SSH environment, AWS Cloud9 leaves behind a hidden subdirectory on the cloud compute instance or your own server that was connected to that environment. You can now safely delete that subdirectory if you want to delete it. The subdirectory is named .c9. It's located in the Environment path directory that you specified when you created the environment.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/aws-cloud9-ug.pdf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).